# How can I reuse a double

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a code which will ask a question the client dims for a crate once the client replies it will ask if you need to add more crate, if the client says yes how would I repeat the same code?  I think I need top add a loop here but I'm not sure how to reuse the same variable.

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the crate Length for your incoming shipment: ");
double l = new double();
l = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Enter the crate Width for your incoming shipment: ");
double w = new double();
w = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Enter the crate Height for your incoming shipmet");
double h = new double();
h = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

double totalDims = new double();
totalDims = l * w * h;
double volKg = new double();
volKg = totalDims / 366;

Console.WriteLine("Your total Vol Kg is {0:0.00}", +volKg);
Console.ReadLine();

Console.Write("Are there any additional crates y/n? ");
char a = new char();
a = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

char y = default(char);
while (a == y)
{
    //Crate Dimensions Entered
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the crate Length for your incoming shipment: ");
    double l = new double();
    l = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the crate Width for your incoming shipment: ");
    double w = new double();
    w = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the crate Height for your incoming shipmet");
    double h = new double();
    h = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, "reuse the same variable?"  What variable?  You have many.

Comment: Just declare your l variable outside the while loop, therefore when you enter the loop you are not reinstantiating l. And then in your while loop have something like l = l + double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Comment: @RomanSidorov :) that is nice way to completely fail assignment.

Comment: @OldProgrammer When you edit a post, make sure you fix everything in it please.

Comment: You don't need to do this: `double volKg = new double();`  (You don't need the _new_).  Google Value versus Reference types to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

As you may have various crats, you should instead use `List(Of T)` instead of a single variable. (Or preferably create a class called `Dimension` with properties like `Lenght`, `Breadth` and `Height`.)

Something like this may help you:

```
            Console.Write("Are there any additional crates y/n? ");
            char a = new char();
            a = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            dim l as new List(Of double)()
            dim w as new List(Of double)()
            dim h as new List(Of double)()

            char y = default(char);
            while (a == y)  '' Revise this condition as it takes `a` input once and keep looping on it, instead it should take input always unless user enters `n`
            {
                //Crate Dimensions Entered
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the crate Length for your incoming shipment: ");
                l.Add(double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));

                Console.WriteLine("Enter the crate Width for your incoming shipment: ");
                w.Add(double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));

                Console.WriteLine("Enter the crate Height for your incoming shipmet");
                h.Add(double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do

I also added some validation to the input

```
    public class CrateDimensions
{
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Length { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static List<CrateDimensions> crates = new List<CrateDimensions>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GetCrateDim();
    }

    static void GetCrateDim()
    {
        double l = GetDim("Please enter the crate Length for your incoming shipment");
        double w = GetDim("Please enter the crate Width for your incoming shipment");
        double h = GetDim("Please enter the crate Height for your incoming shipment");

        crates.Add(new CrateDimensions() { Height = h, Length = l, Width = w });
        double totalDims = new double();
        totalDims = l* w * h;
        double volKg = new double();
        volKg = totalDims / 366;

        Console.WriteLine("Your total Vol Kg is {0:0.00}", +volKg);

        Console.Write("Are there any additional crates y/n? ");
        char a = new char();
        a = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine().ToLower());
        if (a == 'y')
            GetCrateDim();
    }

    static double GetDim(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message + ": ");
        double dimLen = 0;
        while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out dimLen))
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid number");
        return dimLen;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code in the simplest form I can think of:

```
char a = 'y';
while (char.ToLower(a) == 'y')
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the crate Length for your incoming shipment:");
    double l = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the crate Width for your incoming shipment:");
    double w = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the crate Height for your incoming shipment:");
    double h = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    double totalDims = l * w * h;
    double volKg = totalDims / 366;

    Console.WriteLine("Your total Vol Kg is {0:0.00}", volKg);
    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Are there any additional crates y/n? ");
    a = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```